# Need help, CSS and WORDPRESS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress with a theme. This is the logo:
http://oi43.tinypic.com/b67dw8.jpg

My logo is this:
http://oi39.tinypic.com/2jbsa5e.jpg

I'm using Prospect theme on wordpress, it have several css files, there is a css file (layout.css), it has a id logo, and it is

```
#logo {
width: 300px;
float: right;
z-index: 100;
position:absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 0;


}

#logo a {
display: block;
}
```

I've tried by changing settings in this file, but nothing is happening to the logo,
I want that my logo also should come in center.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is after you replace your logo, try adding the following code:

```
#logo {
   top:0 !important;
}
```

Then try changing the value 'top' with pixels 10px, 20px etc, until your logo is centered.

edit: checking at the default theme, it has a value of top:40px. I don't know the height of your image, but as I said play around with this value until it vertically centers.

Comment: well, i myself have tried to put 20 instead of 40, and then saving it but nothing changes on my website,
the author had done this to the editor in wordpress dashboard

   like
@import "css/reset.css";

may be this is the problem?

Comment: did you add the !important at the end of the top?

Comment: What you need to change is the file (edit:corrected filename) layout.css located at the wp-content/themes/prospect/ directory. This HAS to work if it has the !important at the top. Otherwise, if you don't mind your code being a bit messy, you should open the header.php file located inside your theme's directory and place exactly above the </head> tag the code I posted above inside a <style></style> tag

Answer (score 0):

You need to position the logo centered, so you can try to test values op `top` positioning. I think `#logo{top:20px;}` would be ok

Comment: well, i myself have tried to put 20 instead of 40, and then saving it but nothing changes on my website, the author had done this to the editor in wordpress dashboard like @import "css/reset.css"; may be this is the problem?

Comment: no, you should make your changes in `style.css`. You will find the file in the root of the theme. Also if it still doesn't change, use the `!important` rule: `{top:20px !important;}`

Answer (score 0):

Your logo image is bigger than original one.

```
#logo {
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 100;
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
}
```

Just change top:40px into something smaller, like 10px.